# dynamically appending a dict by retrieving list of hierarchy of managers of managers in python ldap3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, ldap, hierarchy

the method **get_employee**,gets details of an employee along with its manager and returns the manager, i have got that part working when run separately, then i am tryng to have another method that gets in the manager and retrieves all its managers in hierarchy till the CEO of that particular employee and append it to the same dict. i tried writing the second method **get_manager** to dynamically add columns to the same dict with manger,manager1,manager2,manager3 etc in a loop.
output of first method
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import ast
import requests
import json
import ldap3
from ldap3 import Server,Connection
from pprint import pprint
host = "ldap://o.com"
user = "CN=P,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=f,DC=r,DC=com"



password = "h"
search_base = "dc=o,dc=f,dc=r,dc=com"
search_filter = '(cn=Pillai, Mamatha)'
df=pd.DataFrame([])
attrs = ['cn','givenName','manager','employeeType','title','department']
server = ldap3.Server(host)
with ldap3.Connection(server,user,password) as conn:
    conn.search(search_base, search_filter, attributes=attrs)
    result=(conn.response_to_json())
    pprint(result)
        #result=json.load(result)
    result=ast.literal_eval(result)
    for j in result.get('entries',[]):
        dfDICT = {'Name':[j.get('attributes').get('cn',None)],
                             'transit':[j.get('attributes').get('department',None)],
                             'Status':[j.get('attributes').get('employeeType',None)],
                             'title':[j.get('attributes').get('title',None)]
                             }
        if j.get('attributes').get('manager'):
            #n=j.get('attributes').get('manager')
            #mn=re.search(r'[^CN=][^,]+,[^,]+',(j.get('attributes').get('manager')))
            p=(j.get('attributes').get('manager'))
            n=(j.get('attributes').get('manager')).replace('\\',"")
            mn=n.replace('CN=',"")
            m=re.search(r'[^,]+,[^,]+',mn)
            if mn is not None:
                dfDICT['manager']=m.group(0)
                manager=m.group(0)



  while True:
        search_filter1 = '(cn='+manager+')'
        attrs1 = ['manager']
        with ldap3.Connection(server,user,password) as conn:
            conn.search(search_base, search_filter1, attributes=attrs1)
            result2=(conn.response_to_json())
            pprint(result2)
            #result=json.load(result)
            result2=ast.literal_eval(result2)
            for i in range():
                for k in result2.get('entries',[]):
                    if k.get('attributes').get('manager'):
                        #p=(j.get('attributes').get('manager'))
                        a=(k.get('attributes').get('manager')).replace('\\',"")
                        b=a.replace('CN=',"")
                        c=re.search(r'[^,]+,[^,]+',b)

                        manager=c.group(0)
                        dfDICT[i]=c.group(0)     
                if manager=='mp':
                    break
```

Comment: Can you create a smaller example by leaving out everything that already works and highlighting the part where you have problems?

Comment: i took off all the methods, now i am geting the json result of all the managers in pprint result2, but i am not able to append all the managers into dfDICT dict

Comment: So, how far does you code get until it fails?  Can you come up with a reproducible example?  Note also that currently your second while loop does not obey to the indentation of the first loop.